# How to get the element from the xml using Xpath Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

```
<employees>
    <employee>
        <firstName>Lokesh</firstName>
        <lastName>Gupta</lastName>
        <department>
            <id>101</id>
            <name>IT</name>
        </department>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

I wanted to get the elements name using Xpath..

I need to count the number of elements that i am getting using `count(//employees/*)` and `count(//employees/employee/department/*)`

it is returning count of each parent..

I need to get the element names as well `//employees/employee/*/name()`  to get the elements name FirstName, LastName and Department..

also `(//employees/employee/department/*/name())` to return name and id.. but it is showing error `javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Unknown nodetype: name .`

Comment: You can try local-name() instead of name(). local-name() returns a string, the element name without namespace information. name() returns a QName, which incudes the namespace.

Comment: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Unknown nodetype: local-name
 at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.compiler.XPathParser.error(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get the elements names (not the value of it). `name()` has to appear the first.
Since `javax` only supports `XPath 1.0`, you can use :

```
concat(name(//employees/employee/*[1]),",",name(//employees/employee/*[2]),",",name(//employees/employee/*[3]))
```

Output :  `firstName,lastName,department`

```
concat(name(//employees/employee/department/*[1]),",",name(//employees/employee/department/*[2]))
```

Output : `id,name`

If you don't know the number of child for each parent element, you should use a loop approach. First, count and store the number of child (`count(//employees/employee/*)`), then make a loop where you increase the position index (`[i]`) at each iteration `//employees/employee/*[i]` `i=i+1`.